# Add param to bash function, totally lost

Tags: bash

I think I am creating this in the correct topic, but feel free to let me know if something more appropriate makes sense. Total bash noob.

I have the following function in my `.bash_profile` to streamline GIT's add->commit->push flow.

```
function lazygit() {
    git add .
    git commit -a -m "$1"
    git push
}
```

And I trigger it like this:

```
> lazygit "Did all the things"
```

I would like to update it to have an **optional** second param which would alter the commit message.

So for this:

```
> lazygit "Did all the things" "Staging"
```

It would do this instead.

```
git commit -a -m "$1 [ Deploy:$2 ]"
```

How can I add this optional param to my function? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write the `git` command like this:

```
git commit -a -m "$1${2:+" [ Deploy:$2 ]"}"
```

If you read the "Parameter Expansion" of the `bash(1)` man page, you will find:

> **`${parameter:+word}`**
>
> Use  Alternate  Value.   If parameter is null or unset, nothing is
>   substituted, otherwise the expansion of word is substituted.

If `$2` has non-empty value, the `[ Deploy:$2 ]` text will be included in your commit message.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. If possible, I would prefer all non-deploy commit messages don't have the bracketed text at all.

Comment: Aaaand that's what you will get.  Have you tried this out?

Comment: Works like a charm. Sorry, I swear all that logic wasn't in there last night. Must have read it too quickly. Appreciate the help.